# I want to add a button after ad to cart of single product page in woo commerce

Tags: wordpress, woocommerce

I am new in woo commerce. I have tried with this code But it is not working

```
function contact_concierge() {
  return '<a class="fsfb" href="'.site_url().'">CONTACT CONCIERGE</a>';
}
add_action('woocommerce_after_cart', 'contact_concierge');
```

I want to add the button after the singple page add to cart table. PLease help me.

Answer (score 0):

The closest place you can get it to is underneath the product title, using:

```
function contact_concierge() {
    echo '<a class="fsfb" href="'.site_url().'">CONTACT CONCIERGE</a>';
}
add_action('woocommerce_single_product_summary', 'contact_concierge');
```

Screenshot:

[image]

Reference:
http://docs.woothemes.com/document/hooks/

Answer (score 0):

```
<?php do_action( 'woocommerce_after_add_to_cart_button' ); ?>
```

and

```
<?php do_action( 'woocommerce_after_add_to_cart_form' ); ?>
```

Are actually much closer to what the OP was looking for... assuming I understood correctly. The former is directly after the add to cart button and is therefore inside the `<form>` element. The latter is after the `</form>` closing tag.

You can see them in the WooCommerce templates `/single-product/add-to-cart/single.php` as well as variable.php and grouped.php.

```
function contact_concierge() {
  echo'<a class="fsfb" href="'.site_url().'">CONTACT CONCIERGE</a>';
}
add_action('woocommerce_after_add_to_cart_button', 'contact_concierge');
```

Comment: Super-late add-on, but: I believe the hooked action needs to `echo` rather than `return` - at least that seems to be the case now with v.2.6.x. I realise it's what the OP put in their question, but worth pointing out for clarity.

Comment: You're right of course. Thanks for the catch, I've edited the answer.